# Up-to-date dictionary of distinct values for column

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers, materialized-views

I have a table with many columns and several million rows like

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
id integer,
thing1 text,
thing2 text,
...
stuff text);
```

How can I manage the relevance of dictionary of unique values of `stuff` column that originally populates like this:

```
INSERT INTO stuff_dict SELECT DISTINCT stuff from foo;
```

Should I manually synchronize (check if new `stuff` value already in `stuff_dict` before every insert/update) or use triggers for each insert/update/delete from `foo` table. In latter case, what is the best design for such a trigger(s)?

UPDATE: view does not suit here, because the `SELECT * FROM stuff_dict` should run as fast as possible (even `CREATE INDEX ON foo(stuff)` does not help much when foo has tens of millions of records).

Answer (score 3):

A materialized view seems to be the simplest option for a large table.

In the trigger function just refresh the view. You can use `concurrently` option (see the pozs's comment below).

```
create materialized view stuff_dict as 
    select distinct stuff
    from foo;

create or replace function refresh_stuff_dict()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    refresh materialized view /*concurrently*/ stuff_dict;
    return null;
end $$;

create trigger refresh_stuff_dict
after insert or update or delete or truncate
on foo for each statement 
execute procedure refresh_stuff_dict();
```

---

While the solution with a materialized view is straightforward it may be suboptimal when the table `foo` is modified frequently. In this case use a table for the dictionary. An index will be helpful.

```
create table stuff_dict as 
    select distinct stuff
    from foo;

create index on stuff_dict(stuff);
```

The trigger function is more complicated and should be fired for each row after insert/update/delete:

```
create or replace function refresh_stuff_dict()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    do_insert boolean := tg_op = 'INSERT' or tg_op = 'UPDATE' and new.stuff <> old.stuff;
    do_delete boolean := tg_op = 'DELETE' or tg_op = 'UPDATE' and new.stuff <> old.stuff;
begin
    if do_insert and not exists (select 1 from stuff_dict where stuff = new.stuff) then
        insert into stuff_dict values(new.stuff);
    end if;
    if do_delete and not exists (select 1 from foo where stuff = old.stuff) then
        delete from stuff_dict
        where stuff = old.stuff;
    end if;
    return case tg_op when 'DELETE' then old else new end;
end $$;

create trigger refresh_stuff_dict
after insert or update or delete
on foo for each row
execute procedure refresh_stuff_dict();
```

Comment: Despite its name `refresh materialized view concurrently` will block the execution until it is finished (just other session's reads will not be blocked until the refresh completes). It is actually slower than without `concurrently` on greater datasets. -- But yes, materialized views are created for the OP use case.